# Joda failing in parsing RFC 2822 format

Tags: java, jodatime

This is what I am tryin....

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(pubDate);
        return dateTime;
```

and there is a result :(

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sat, 09 Apr 2016 09:43:00 +0200"
                                                              at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
```

I tried a lot of other formating options per documentation but still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) must not be English (and the month and day of the week names you're parsing are in English). You can use [`DateTimeFormatter.withLocale(Locale)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) to override your local locale with something like

```
String pubDate = "Sat, 09 Apr 2016 09:43:00 +0200";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withLocale(new Locale("en_US")).parseDateTime(pubDate);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Comment: Well I guess this is the reason why it worked on emulator, and failed on a real device. Thanks